# diff between my current uncommited code and the remote head on the same branch

Tags: git

How to see the diff between my current uncommited code and the remote head on the same branch.

I work on master branch, and at some point I want to see the same result as:

```
git commit
git pull
git diff <my commit>
```

but without really pulling (and better without even committing). Just to know what's different between my current work and the remote head.

Answer (score 2):

Git pull is just a git fetch followed by a git merge.

In your case, get the remote changes locally with a git fetch, then compare to the remote branch. Say you're on master and want to compare with the remote branch origin/master, this will be :

```
git fetch
git diff origin/master
```

By default git diff compare what is not indexed with the given commit, if you want to compare what is indexed, you need to used `git diff --cached`